# Simple node.js program can't get data from form

Tags: html, node.js, forms

So, I'm really not good with backend development, but I tried to make this simple program:

HTML file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form action = "http://localhost:3000/test" method="post">
        <input type = "text" name = "firstname" />
        <input type = "text" name = "lastname" />
        <input type ="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Server file:

```
    var express = require("express");

var app = express();

app.get("/", function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html")
})

app.post("/test", function(req, res){
    console.log("testing")
    var unbuffered = "";
    req.on("data", function(data)
    {
        unbuffered += data
    })
    console.log(unbuffered)

    req.on("end", function()
    {
        console.log("done")
    })
})

app.listen(3000);
```

I use the "unbuffered" variable because before it printed something bizarre.  Now it's just printing nothing.  The "testing" and "done" print.  But that's it.  How do I solve this?

Comment: `console.log(unbuffered)` is executed before any of the `data` events occur. If you want to log the contents of `unbuffered` after all data was received you need to log that in the `end` event callback.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [body parser from express](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html). Alter to this:

```js
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }) );

app.get("/", function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html")
})

app.post("/test", function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body);
    res.end('<html><head><body><h3>Got it</h3></body></head></html>');
})

app.listen(3000);
```